# Is there something like the "TeX input method" in vim?

Tags: vim, input, unicode, symbols, tex

Emacs has a feature called the [TeX input method](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TeXInputMethod): you can input unicode symbols by typing the associated (La)TeX macro. For example, typing `\lambda` gives λ.

Is there a package that gives a similar functionality in vim?

Comment: Have a look at [latex-unicoder](https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim)

Comment: @hbaderts thanks, this is totally what I want. if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a package called [`latex-unicoder`](https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim) on Github. It can be installed e.g. with the [Vundle.vim](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) plugin manager by adding

```
Plugin 'joom/latex-unicoder.vim'
```

to your `.vimrc` file and calling `:PluginInstall`.

When you are in Normal Mode, you can call `C-l` (which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), and then directly type in the LaTeX command of the symbol, e.g. `\lambda`. This inserts the Unicode symbol λ into your document. The plugin even features an auto-completion by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

Have you seen http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net ?  Pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

As an example (though not with lambda), this will compile to show the unicode π character in your .tex document:

[image]

Comment: I think shva wants something that will automatically convert `\lambda` to `λ`, for example. It doesn't look like this package does that.

Comment: That's actually exactly what the package will do.  It won't do it in real-time, but it will save the file down with unicode encoding and interpret the macros appropriately.

Comment: Where in the manual does it talk about that? I don't see it mentioned in the docs, but I guess it could be a feature not mentioned.

Comment: I actually use this package when I'm typesetting latex and I wasn't aware that this package does what I was looking for. To be clear, I'm looking for something that will replace, e.g. `\lambda` to λ, within the text editor, regardless of whether or not I'm editing a tex document.

Comment: what @hbaderts suggested in the comment to my original post actually looks like what I want